# My CSS isn't being applied at all. What is my error?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to load a CSS file to HTML to style it except the CSS doesn't load. I placed both the files in the same directory

I have an HTML file called Homepage.html and a CSS file called Homepage.css:

```
<html>
    <title>
            Welcome to Sids World!
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
    </title>

    <body>
        <div id="header"> <!-- menu here --> 
            This Site is Under Construction 
        </div>
        <div><!-- global division -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Furthermore, my CSS file (located in the same directory) has the following code:

```
body
{
    font-size:100%;
    background-color:red;

}
#header
{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:4em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

I expect when this loads that the background of the entire site will be red and the background surrounding my text will be blue, but this does not occur. What am I missing here?

The file paths of both files are:

C:\Sid\Rutgers\ComputerScience\SiteForDeploy\htmlfiles\Homepage.html

C:\Sid\Rutgers\ComputerScience\SiteForDeploy\htmlfiles\Homepage.css

I am using Sublime Text Editor for my processing if that helps

Comment: If the css file's name is title cased, change the href to be title cased too (`Homepage.css`)

Comment: Also; what do you see?

Comment: `<link>` should be self closing, and in your filesystem you have `Homepage.css` but in the `<link>` tag you have `homepage.css`.  Also, do you have a `<head>` element you can stuff the `<title>` and `<link>` in?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see the current html material, but no CSS formatting, background is white, the font is the default of my browser, size is default

Comment: I closed the link tag so it now reads <link .... />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is twofold. Firstly, you fail to specify a `<head>` section for your document. Secondly, your `<link>` tag is within your `<title>` tag. The `<link>` tag should be within `<head>`, but not within `<title>`. Change to this and you'll see pretty colors:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    Welcome to Sids World!
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"> <!-- menu here -->
    This Site is Under Construction
  </div>
  <div>   <!-- global division -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the system said I had to wait

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <title>
            Welcome to Sids World!
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
    </title>

    <body>
        <div id="header"> <!-- menu here --> 
            This Site is Under Construction 
        </div>
        <div>   <!-- global division -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

should be changed to

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Welcome to Sids World!
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Homepage.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header"> <!-- menu here --> 
            This Site is Under Construction 
        </div>
        <div>   <!-- global division -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Css url's are case sensitive, so you'll need `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Homepage.css">`

Otherwise your code is working just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/3deg1h05/

Comment: I copy and pasted that in place of my link code and its still not working

Comment: Depending on the server operating system ( Windows and mac filesystems are typically case-insenitive; all others are typically case-sensitive)